# How to Connect CP1L (Omron) FINS/TCP through a switch to (Keyence) DL-EP1

Tags: tcp, ip, plc, server-communication, fins

Alright this may be impossible or i may be an idiot but here it is. I am trying to connect a Omron CP1L PLC through a switch and and to a Keyence DL-EP1. So far i have my PC hooked into a switch and my PLC hooked into the switch and also the Keyence communication DL-EP1 hooked into the switch. I am able to ping both of these independently through the PC with no issues. However I am having issues getting the PLC and the DL-EP1 to communicate together through CXProgrammer.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "connect"....it sounds like you've already done that. If you would like to communicate with a device through that DL-EP1 to your PLC on EtherNet/IP, then you will need to use Network Configurator, a software application included in the CX-One Software Suite. You will need to reference the appropriate Keyence manual to determine what the size of the input and output tags are, and then broadcast them to your PLC from the Keyence device using Network Configurator.